# Unity command line arguments for android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

Please pardon my ignorance, relatively new to working with Unity3D. I am working on automating Unity3d builds from the command line.

I am looking for command line arguments to build apk & xcode project.
[Unity's documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html) does mention arguments to build a standalone Mac OSX player (-buildOSXPlayer) and a standalone Windows player (-buildWindowsPlayer) but not for android and iOS.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -executeMethod  command line parameter is a very simple option to  invoke any function in any of your scripts - which you can then use to do pretty much anything, including firing off an Android build.

Comment: Yes, that's what I ended up doing. Created a special Editor class with methods responsible for building for Android and iOS.

Answer (score 8):

Start with Unity's own [documentation for command line builds for iOS and android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CommandLineArguments.html).

For example, put this script in your Assets/Editor folder:

```
// C# example
using UnityEditor;
class Autobuilder
{
     [MenuItem ("File/AutoBuilder/iOS")]
     static void PerformBuild ()
     {
         string[] scenes = { "Assets/MyScene.unity" };

         string buildPath = "../../../Build/iOS";

         // Create build folder if not yet exists
         Directory.CreateDirectory(buildPath);

         BuildPipeline.BuildPlayer(scenes, buildPath, BuildTarget.iOS, BuildOptions.Development);
     }
}
```

You can actually run this script in the Unity application by going to File -> Autobuilder -> iOS

To run on command line, it looks something like this:

```
/Applications/Unity/Unity.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity -quit -batchmode -executeMethod Autobuilder.PerformBuild -email me@email.com -password myPassword
```

Of course, you're going to want to check the [debug log](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) for any errors:

> Mac OS X  ~/Library/Logs/Unity/Editor.log
>   Windows XP    C:\Documents and Settings\username\Local Settings\Application Data_\Unity\Editor\Editor.log
>   Windows Vista/7   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Unity\Editor\Editor.log

Comment: This only launches Unity Hub in my case

Comment: How can I specify the exact project to load and build?